# Stored procedure, function, or cursor mysql combine multiple rows to one row without using group_concat

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I have a problem in production database. Currently, I have task like this below image.

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kAY4.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgBxp.png)

I have done this task using `group_concat`. But, I can use this method/function since string or character have limit in **1024**. I can change this even administrator or someone. Because application will down temporary. This is too risk in production.

So, I'm gonna ask if someone have idea or ever create stored procedure, function, or cursor like `group_concat`.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

The setting is connection-based and a dynamic variable. Increase it to 200000 below, for instance.

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 200000;
SELECT @@group_concat_max_len;
+------------------------+
| @@group_concat_max_len |
+------------------------+
|                 200000 |
+------------------------+
```

See the manual page for [`group_concat_max_len`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len).

Comment: I can change `group_concat_max_len`. This is prerequirement @Drew.

Comment: In theory setting the var would not be relevant for a stored proc. This would be a great question for a bounty in a few days.

Comment: I just ask if there is someone ever implemented group_concat behaviour, job, or function in stored procedure, function or cursor. Maybe this difficult question or someone never have same problem like me, caused I have search many resource but didn't found anything

Comment: It would be a function that applies for all rows, yet collapsed on a column row, for just that column on that row, amidst other columns that run vertical for all rows (as you know). And most people would be thankful the function already exists that employs the flexibility with the Separator and Order By within the group_concat. I would be happy to add a bounty for you btw. I highly doubt you would get any takers though. I would spend your energies on a server upgrade.

Comment: @BambangLuPS do you understand what is being said here?  You can set this inside the procedure.  You do not need to change the server configuration, or resort to hacks, which will hurt your performance with iterative copying of larger and larger strings.